# Will the log file be generated for an independent service?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, service

My application runs in tomcat say tomcat1, some part of the code is started as a different service say in tomcat2, now there is a log file which is configured to log and is present in WEB-INF\classes in tomcat1, so when the service that is running in tomcat2 starts, will the logging present in that code will also be seen in the same logging file of tomcat1 ?

Comment: as far as your services are deployed in same tomcat you will get 1 log file as per configuration in each module. I think you should get basics first without deploying a service how can some part of it be running in another tomcat...!!!

Comment: The code is deployed in Tomcat1, and some part of it which is a different thread is started from tomcat2, but there is only one log4j file in tomcat1. But I don't get the logs from the clases running from tomcat2.

Comment: do i need to configure a differnt log4j file for tomcat2 ?

Comment: Firstly i would like to know are you trying to run each thread in a different server if so why because the web server itself can handle n number of threads. As far as your question is concerned if you are starting something in a different tomcat (which is tomcat2 in your case) then you definitely need to add a logger to get status of your app flow otherwise it will be hard to debug.